# php error class cannot be resolved to a type, live on web

Tags: php

DMaster again... I feel such a noobie!! Anyway... So On my workstation, my whole project works just fine after many hours on it. Then I upload it live and turns up with a ton of errors. After noticing that php v7 was not being implemented, and fixing that issue. I got the following error log, 'No connection to the database was establish' Funny thing, it knows all the info but no password. Yet, I check all my files and is all there. So, I went ahead, and place if(!data_con) die('No Object was Created') and BHAM, sure enough. The class was not being created. It works just fine on my workstation, but life is not. So, if I pull up the file with my FTP and check on the class, and it gives me that error: the class cannot be resolved to a type. I open the same file on my workstation, it doesn't show that error. I have php 7.2  [File of regarding the Question](https://pastebin.com/V5m97xHE)... Any suggestion would be great.
    //db.php

```
class condata
{
private $host     = 'et40433I3G40333N4347y488149';
private $user     = 'et434948443G48333O1M3E3J413Gy47483K4649';
private $password = 'et323G422C3K42332H403K421L1L1M49';
private $database = 'et434948443G483O331M3E433Iy473E3J3H49';
private $port     = '';
private $socket   = '';

public function __construct(){}

public function get_host()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->host);
    return $request;
}

public function get_user()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->user);
    return $request;
}

public function get_password()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->password);
    $request = '';
    return $request;
}

public function get_database()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->database);
    return $request;
}

public function get_port()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->port);
    return $request;
}

public function get_socket()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->socket);
    return $request;
}

private info_(string $info){....  }

}//closing class

$db = new condata();


if(!$db)
{
    die('No Object was created!');
}

$host     = $db->get_host();
$user     = $db->get_user();
$password = $db->get_password();
$database = $db->get_database();
$port     = $db->get_port();
$socket   = $db->get_socket();

if(!$password)
{
    die('No Object was created!');
}
```

Comment: nothing in the code above make a connection to a db, just sets some variables

Comment: so people like Smith, go around and just give a no, no... Who said i wanted to make a connection??? What I wanted to know why my ('Class Object is not being created. The rest is history! I am sure that was implied as a question') /* " So, I went ahead, and place if(!data_con) die('No Object was Created') and BHAM, sure enough. The class was not being created."  */ but thanks for the no help, The other guy did better than you. [$db = new condata();] for some reason on live web should be ->  $db = new condata; <-- no "()". That did the job!. Thank you...

Comment: sorry but you say in your question  " I got the following error log, 'No connection to the database was establish' "; hence my comment, if that's not an issue dont include it in your question. Focus on the specific question at hand for the best change of getting an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at get_password:

```
public function get_password()
{
    $request = $this->info_($this->password);
    $request = '';
    return $request;
}
```

You're getting the password throught `$this->info` (which is not properly declared, on purpose I guess) and then overriding it:

```
$request = '';
```

An empty string will be converted to `false` boolean in the if

```
if(!$password)
```

Also, `private info_` should be `private function info_`

Edit: Consider using static variables if they really are.

Comment: Thank you, I did find those mistakes afterward, since on workstation I don't have a password, I place those there, and forgot about them. Need to keep those notes near so it won't happen. But I figure it out. It was the "()" That wasn't letting me build my class object. `$db = new condata();` should be `$db = new condata;` on live line. Yeah, go figure. On the workstation, no complains. Jaja! Any way. Thank you. I tried to place this as the accepted answer because it did mention of the password being returned as an empty string. The other was just mistype on my part. Copy Paste Right

Comment: The parenteses weren't a problem, I guess, your both checks had the same ouput. And you welcome mate! :D

Comment: Yes indeed. Jaja. What a day. Well. This is the best answer. I just can't bump it up.  I would if I could. Now, where did I leave those notes! -> I guess that should be in a new thread for that question :)